Position vector in the formula relating the velocity in rotating frame to inertial frame
When learning the position vector $\:\mathbf r$, I was told it was not a real vector because it is tied to a particular coordinate system. Now I have learned that the derivative of any vector $\:\mathbf C\:$ in a rotating frame and the inertial frame can be related via (equation \ref{9.8} in $^{\prime\prime}$An Introduction to Mechanics$^{\prime\prime}$ by D.Kleppner-R.Kolenkow, CUP 2nd Edition 2014),
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf C}{\mathrm d\, t}\right)_{in}\!\!\!\!\!=\left(\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf C}{\mathrm d\,t}\right)_{rot}\!\!\!\!\!+\boldsymbol{\Omega\times} \mathbf C
\tag{9.8}\label{9.8}
\end{equation}
The author claims that $\:\mathbf C\:$ can be replaced by $\:\mathbf r$, then the velocity in a rotating frame can be related to the inertial velocity via
\begin{equation}
\mathbf v_{in}=\mathbf v_{rot}+\boldsymbol{\Omega\times} \mathbf r
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathbf v_{in}\:$ denotes the velocity in the inertial frame, $\:\mathbf v_{rot}\:$ denotes the velocity in the rotation frame. $\:\boldsymbol \Omega\:$ denotes the angular velocity of the rotating frame.
What confuses me is how we can replace $\:\mathbf C\:$ with $\:\mathbf r\:$ if $\:\mathbf r\:$ is not a real vector. Even if we can, I wonder to which coordinate system this $\:\mathbf r\:$ is tied, and where the origin is.

Position is a real vector, when phrased properly. If position is defined as the displacement from an "origin" to a point in space, that is a vector.  Note that the fact that we had to include the origin aligns with your phrasing "... tied to a particular coordinate system."
The equation for rotation given has a specific coordinate system.  $\Omega$ and $r$ are vectors with respect to an "origin" of the rotation (a point along the axis of rotation).  It would be possible to come up with an equation for a rotating frame that was not tied to this origin, but the math would be much more complicated and it would not add any insight you could not achieve with a set of coordinate system transformations.
